# Ionic 2 - How to keep ion-input editable but not showing keyboard

Tags: html, ionic2

I have my own keyboard and i want to keep input editable but i don't want that open the keyboard.

I tried:

- use readonly: but with it, i cant focus and paste
- (ionFocus) - keyboard.hide when focus, but i cant select

Someone know how to keep editable, but without keyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add "disabled" attribute at your ion-input.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" disabled="true" placeholder="Input disabled">
</ion-input>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add some explanation to make your answer more useful to others?